# Any reason to define types in dll? Like #define MODULE_NAME_INT8 __int8

Tags: c++

So I am going through some code at work and while I am not an expert in c++ yet I think it is safe to say the code is a bit of mess. Still I would like confirmation on something. In the code every type is defined like so:

```
#define MODULE_NAME_INT8 __int8
```

The same for unsigned, 16, 32 and 64 bit as well as bool, null, true and false. Is there possibly some reason for this? It is in a dll, and other parts of the application is written in C# so maybe there is something with this I have not thought of?

It really seems like a complete waste and a misuse of define to me. I mean the type name is in the define, it is basically just renaming the type, why clutter the code like this? Am I right or am I missing something?

Comment: __int8 is Windows only. Ever heard of other platforms?

Comment: Probably better to abstract these types into a common header I would have thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think those defines make sense. If this code is a bit old, MSVC 2008 and before do not have stdint.h nor cstdint. So the standard type `int8_t` cannot be used and the programmer decided to hide the Windows specific `__int8` behind a define to only have to change the define if the code has to be ported to another platform (or simply a different compiler)

Comment: That is exactly what I was missing, I was thinking of __int8 as int8_t. The project is MSVC 2010, but it is version 2 of the application, possibly this part of the code is older.

Answer (score 1):

Double underscore before type is compiler-specific. Typically you can see defines like this one if the code is supposed to be built using different compiler or platform, so that you can build from the same source code, and types remain the same.

Although this clutters the code, using for example just "int" may be dangerous in case you want to build for multiple platforms, because in C++ int has no standard-defined size (int may be 1,2,4,8 bytes).

C++11 [introduced fixed types for this purpose](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer): int8_t, int16_t, and so on, but since your code was most probably created long before this, it does not take advantage of this, and goes the "old-fashioned" way.

Answer (score 0):

Having a header file with all data types used by the application is very common practice in commercial software. 
It's more of a thinking ahead kind of measure than a maintain compatibility. The purpose is to make the code easily portable and easy to maintain.

Since there is no guarantee that the code will not have to run a different architecture which uses different sizes for the common data types, the practice is a very good one.